# getting create function to work on a second model in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, express, mean

I'm trying to get my second model to load in my MEAN application and I'm having a hard and I'm not really sure what the issue is

this is what I have in my express application

```
app.post("/api/maintenance_requests/:tenant_name/users", function(req, res){
  Maintenance_Request.findOne({tenant_name: req.body.tenant_name}).then(function(){
     User.create({name: req.body.name, category: req.body.category, division: req.body.division}).then(function(user){
       maintenance_request.users.push(user).save(function(maintenance_request){
        res.json(user);
        })
     })
  })
})
```

this my is my factory for the create which is inside of my show controller function

```
function UserFactoryFunction($resource){
    return $resource ("/api/maintenance_requests/:tenant_name/users", {tenant_name: "@tenant_name"}, {
      //need to specify which methods are being used for the second model, users
        get: {method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: false},
        create: {method: "POST"}
      })
    }
```

and this is my function for the show controller that contains my create method

```
function UserShowControllerFunction ($state, $stateParams, UserFactory ) {
      this.tenant = UserFactory.get({tenant_name: $stateParams.tenant_name}, (tenant) => {
        this.users = tenant.users

        //create new user attached to one maintenance_request
        this.newUser = new UserFactory()
        this.newUser.create = function(){
          this.newUser.$save(function(user){
            $state.reload()
        })

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In Angular, factories are singletons, so `new UserFactory()` is unnecessary!

Comment: Where in this flow does the failure happen? Does the data make it to the backend? Is the mongo `create` call successful?

Comment: @Pytth I'm not getting any error in the console or terminal. When I click the submit on my form, the page doesn't reload with the new information. Nothing happens

Comment: @Nyk Keep in mind that doing things this way -- via ajax -- does not cause a page to refresh by default. Further, you can see if the call is making it to your server via the network panel in your browser -- which could also be used to see what you are getting back. One suggestion I would make is using the base `$http` object for calls as it is a bit more straightforward.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thanks!